# PCI-E Devices not Detected in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, pci

I have been using Ubuntu 19.10 since it came out without issue for my home server.  Today I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and the system no longer detects my Mellanox ConnectX-2 and my LSI 9207-8i (two port HBA).  Both of these devices have worked for years on Ubuntu 18 and 19.10.  I am able to enter the LSI HBA menu at boot and it detects all the drives, so it is not an issue with the actual HBA card from what I can tell.  When I run LSPCI, I only see the onboard PCI devices, built into the motherboard (including the built in graphics).  The two listed above, which are plugged into the same PCI-E slots as they have always been no longer appears after the upgrade.

Any suggestions?  Thus far I have tried both devices in another machine with Ubuntu 19.10 and they work fine.

Update 2020-04-24 14:50 EST: Was able to get the system to see both PCI-E cards after adding pci=nocrs to kernel.  My friend helped me diagnose that the kernel was not enumerating my PCI Bridge/PLX for some reason.  So for the time being, it is working, however I still need to find out why this was never an issue with previous versions.

Comment: Two possible issues come to mind: A) you have compiled/installed a kernel module on your own or B) Canonical removed the modules from their kernel build. I would check with the hardware vendor for further information on Ubuntu 20.04 compatibility.